# Why are there so many questions without an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

Currently, less than half of the questions on the "Newest Questions" page have an accepted answer, although most of them actually do have answers. [This question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/21048/why-and-how-much-is-riding-big-chainring-frong-small-cog-rear-a-negative-practic) for example didn't get any activity in the last days but has two answers with upvotes, the higher-voted one even seems to address all points in the question.

My question is: Why are there so few "accepted-answered" questions here compared to e.g. SO, where > 75% of questions have an accept within the first few days? One point might be the far lower number of users here, but I feel that some askers might not know (or care) about accepting. Maybe we don't force the Q&A-format enough?

Comment: Vorac's acceptance rate has dropped off this year, it was about 80% previously. Maybe he's busy, but I don't think he's a good example of this issue.

Comment: A user's acceptance rate used to be shown, but it's not now. People could decide if it was worthwhile spending time on their questions.

Comment: @andy256 I always wondered why acceptance rate is no longer shown.

Comment: Useful to note that right now, most of these questions (but not all) are asked by people of rep < 100ish. So possibly it could be an unfamiliarity thing.

Comment: Personally, I think that upvotes are more indicative of a good answer than acceptance. I can't even count the times I've seen an accepted answer (on lots of SE sites, not just Bicycles) right above another, clearly better answer with 10x as many votes.

Comment: smaller SO sites usually struggle to get votes and accepts, where SE and other busy sites have the opposite problem - questions disappear off the front page before anyone sees them, let alone votes on them. Here it can take a few days but the high-rep users seem to make a point of trying to answer every answerable question, or at least leave helpful comments

Comment: trying to get new users to accept an answer is a common problem. Once the new user has seen an answer that's good enough they apparently don't ever come back to their question, so comments saying "please accept" are ignored. But the comments do help sometimes - on SE I've seen "your accept rate is so low I don't see any point answering your question" type comments.

Comment: @Mσᶎ I also used to go to SO for a while. Back then, they still had the acceptance rate right next to the user's name, so the kinds of comments you mentioned were pretty standard. The accept rate is no longer shown, so you often don't notice anymore.